# Cancel pending recv?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

Hi I'm working on a networking project. I've a socket that is listening incoming data. Now I want to archive this: Socket will receive only 100 packets. And there is 3-4 clients. They are sending random data packets infinitely. I'll receive 100 packets and later I'll process them. After process I'll re-start receiving. But at this time there are some pending send() >> recv() operations. Now I want to cancel/discard pending recv operations. I think we'll recv datas and we'll not process them. Any other suggestions? (sorry for bad question composition)

Comment: Just do not call the `recv` function. The OS will burn them

Comment: @EdHeal No it won't, not unless the receiver closes the socket.

Comment: @EJP - There is a time out mechanism involved.

Comment: @EdHeal There is no timeout mechanism that discards pending data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutdown and close the connection. That will cancel everything immediately.

Better yet, rearchitect your application and network protocol so that you can reliably tell how much data to receive.

On Windows you can cancel outstanding receives using CancelIO, but that might result in lost data if the receive just happened to read something.

Comment: Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738547(v=vs.85).aspx for an explanation of how socket shutdown works. The information there is 90% cross-platform and 10% Windows specific.

Comment: That's almost correct except that on Unix you'll have to do this: 
 signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
since closing a socket while another thread is waiting leads to a broken pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select()` or `poll()` loops. 
you can use signal. `recv()` will return on receiving a signal so you can send a signal from another task to the task that blocks on `recv()`. But you need to make sure you don't specify `SA_RESTART` (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O for more details

Answer (score 1):

I would go with non-blocking sockets + cancellation socket.
You'll have to read into dedicated incremental buffer (as recv() may not receive all the data expected at once - this would be the case if you can only process full messages) and return to select()/poll() in your loop, where you can safely sit and wait for:

- next data
- next connection
- cancellation event from a cancellation socket, to which your other thread will send a cancellation signal (some trivial send()).

UPD: the trivial event may be the number of the socket in the array or its handle - something to identify which one you'd like to cancel.

Comment: Correct (but use `epoll()`!) `select()` and `poll()` are antiques.

Comment: That's true for networking applications, but complicates porting (like WSAPoll(), analogous to poll() only appeared in Windows Vista). So if the number of connections can be well projected as _limited_ and cross-platformness is the issue - I'd go with select(). Although you're right - it's insanely slow when it comes to uncontrollable amount of connections.

Comment: Well okay there are some edge cases